# JFrame Not Appearing (mac issue?)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am aware that several people have posted about this but no solution has worked for me. Can anyone tell me why a JFrame is not appearing from my code.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUITestWindow extends JFrame{
    public void GUI(){
       setTitle("Welcome");
       setResizable(true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setSize(600,600);
       setVisible(true);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUITestWindow a = new GUITestWindow();
        a.GUI();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: But that is still not working@JB NIzet

Comment: The same code tends to work on windows and not on mac

Comment: It works fine here (before, and after fixing the code, but you should definitely respect the threading rules).

Comment: @JBNizet, are you using mac or windows?

Comment: I'm on a Mac (macOS High Sierra).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you ran your commands in the wrong order. Sometimes, when setting up a JFrame, it will not appear if you run it in the run order. Try redoering:

```
setTitle("Welcome");
setResizable(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(600,600);
setVisible(true);
```

to:

```
setVisible(true);
setResizable(true);
setSize(600, 600);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Welcome");
```

This doesn't always work, but it's worth a try. :)